# How to get consumerTag in spring-rabbitmq 1.x

Tags: spring-amqp

the spring-rabbitmq config is like

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
```

I want to canceling a consumer , use `channel.basicCannel(consumerTag)`

when i use `ChannelAwareMessageListener` in spring-rabbitmq 2.x version, `consumerTag` are
in `MessageProperties`,
but my online service is use 1.x version, there has no `consumerTag` in `MessageProperties`,
so i cant use the basicCancel api

my full listener code below

```
public class RPCListener implements ChannelAwareMessageListener {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RPCListener.class);

    @Autowired
    private MessagePropertiesConverter messagePropertiesConverter;

    private MessageConverter messageConverter = new SimpleMessageConverter();

    @Autowired
    private AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;
    private Boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
        try {
            log.error("DeliveryTag(): {}", message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag());
            if (flag) {
                log.error("canceling....");
                //If true, messages will be requeued and possibly
                channel.basicRecover(true);
                // there is no consumerTag property in MessageProperties 
                //channel.basicCancel(message.getMessageProperties().getConsumerTag());
                return;
            }
            amqpTemplate.send(message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), message);
            channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get consumerTag?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.1.3 is 7 years old; the `consumerTag` was added to `MessageProperties` in [1.4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-457).

The only supported 1.x version is 1.7.14 - see [the project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp#learn).

1.7.x will no longer be supported after this year.

However; you should **NOT manually cancel the consumer**; stop the container instead.

Comment: However; you should NOT manually cancel the consumer; stop the container instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get the listen-container bean from applicationContext,and call stop. it works,

Comment: @GaryRussell What if I have a container with multiple queues, each having multiple consumers (with one for each app instance) and I need it to stop listening only specific queues? I guessed I can use something like `channel.basicCancel(myConsumerTag)`

Comment: No!! Remove the queue from the container instead.

Comment: @GaryRussell Actually I have to pause it, keeping messages in queue for a delay reading, I cannot remove the queue

Comment: Removing it from the container does not remove it from the broker. Just add it back to the container again when you want to restart consuming.